# Efficient pair-wise operations within groups in r

Tags: r, for-loop, datatable, data.table, pairwise

I have a dataset containing firms and their performance measures alongside other information. I want to define "social aspiration level" for each firm based on a weighted average performance of all the other firms in that industry (excluding the focal firm).

More spicifically:

[image: formula]

Where i denotes the focal firm and t denotes time t. j denotes other firms in the same industry and P is size of the company, and I is the income.

For the given dataset below:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.table(
   "Firm" = c(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),times=2),rep(c("E","F","G","H"),times=2)),
   "Year" = c(rep(c(2001,2002),each=4),rep(c(2001,2002),each=4)),
   "Income" = sample(100:200,16),
   "Size" = sample(1:20,16),
   "Industry_Code" = rep(c(100,200),each=8)
   )
df

     Firm Year Income Size Industry_Code
 1:    A 2001    130    7           100
 2:    B 2001    178   10           100
 3:    C 2001    150    9           100
 4:    D 2001    113    4           100
 5:    A 2002    166   14           100
 6:    B 2002    141    1           100
 7:    C 2002    149   11           100
 8:    D 2002    142   20           100
 9:    E 2001    197    5           200
10:    F 2001    124   19           200
11:    G 2001    189   13           200
12:    H 2001    168   18           200
13:    E 2002    156   15           200
14:    F 2002    108    2           200
15:    G 2002    171    3           200
16:    H 2002    125   17           200
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
     Firm Year Income Size Industry_Code    SA
 1:    A 2001    130    7           100 40.91667
 2:    B 2001    178   10           100 41.21429
 3:    C 2001    150    9           100 50.38889
 4:    D 2001    113    4           100 27.64286
 5:    A 2002    166   14           100 22.53571
 6:    B 2002    141    1           100 10.83420
 7:    C 2002    149   11           100 12.44329
 8:    D 2002    142   20           100 15.22143
 9:    E 2001    197    5           200 13.75556
10:    F 2001    124   19           200 41.37778
11:    G 2001    189   13           200 22.53439
12:    H 2001    168   18           200 35.85714
13:    E 2002    156   15           200 20.84493
14:    F 2002    108    2           200 34.81845
15:    G 2002    171    3           200 24.77778
16:    H 2002    125   17           200 23.38333
```

Note that for example, for for A in year 2001, SA is given by ((178/4+150/3+113/4)/3).
A for loop will do what I want, but it's immensly slow.
A data.table solution is preferable, and I want to iterate it by grouping industry and year.

I know developing a solution might be time-consuming, so any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: In the data, there is no `133`

Comment: Perhaps `df[, SA := sum(Income)/sum(Size), .(Firm, Year)]` or `df[, SA := sum(Income/Size), .(Firm, Year)]`

Comment: @akrun Ah, sorry, I had set it with a different seed initially.  Will edit  it right now.

Comment: Not clear about the logic.  Why is it 178/4.  Here 178 is for Firm B and 4 is from D

Comment: @akrun Sorry for the initial confusion. The logic is that the focal firm's performance is excluded (thus, only 178,150, and 113 are included for the performance). However, these performance measures are weighted, so the performance of firm B (178) is divided by the absolute difference between the size of firm A and firm B + 1 (|7-10|+1 = 4). Likewise, performance of firm C (150) is divided by  the absolute difference between the size of firm A and firm C + 1 (|7-9|+1 = 3). And so on...
I hope it adds more clarification

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Once again, my apologies! The summation is over income, divided by the difference of sizes. I edited the formula (now I is income, P is size).

Comment: you might want to correct your eqn using an online latex renderer with `SA_{it} = \sum_{j=1, i \neq j}^N \frac{I_{jt} / (1 + |P_{jt} - P_{it}|) }{N - 1}`

Comment: Do you mean the equation doesn't reflect the described desired outcome? Or just changing the format from picture to latex?

Comment: @chinsoon12Yes, looks better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will be any faster than your loop since `sapply` is essentially a loop but here's a relatively straightforward implementation of the formula with data.table grouping.

```
df[, sa := (sapply(Size, function(s) sum(Income/(1 + abs(s - Size)))) - Income)/(.N - 1), 
   .(Year, Industry_Code)]

df
#     Firm Year Income Size Industry_Code       sa
#  1:    A 2001    130    7           100 40.91667
#  2:    B 2001    178   10           100 41.21429
#  3:    C 2001    150    9           100 50.38889
#  4:    D 2001    113    4           100 27.64286
#  5:    A 2002    166   14           100 22.53571
#  6:    B 2002    141    1           100 10.83420
#  7:    C 2002    149   11           100 22.83939
#  8:    D 2002    142   20           100 15.22143
#  9:    E 2001    197    5           200 13.75556
# 10:    F 2001    124   19           200 41.37778
# 11:    G 2001    189   13           200 22.53439
# 12:    H 2001    168   18           200 35.85714
# 13:    E 2002    156   15           200 20.84493
# 14:    F 2002    108    2           200 34.81845
# 15:    G 2002    171    3           200 24.77778
# 16:    H 2002    125   17           200 23.38333
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
Firm Year Income Size Industry_Code
    A 2001    130    7           100
    B 2001    178   10           100
    C 2001    150    9           100
    D 2001    113    4           100
    A 2002    166   14           100
    B 2002    141    1           100
    C 2002    149   11           100
    D 2002    142   20           100
    E 2001    197    5           200
    F 2001    124   19           200
    G 2001    189   13           200
    H 2001    168   18           200
    E 2002    156   15           200
    F 2002    108    2           200
    G 2002    171    3           200
    H 2002    125   17           200
')
```

Comment: It's WAYYYY faster than mine. I didn't even wanted to post mine since I knew it wasn't nearly close to being efficient. Many thanks!